# Usar elemento de una celda de Excel en un recorrido, Python, Peticiones, web scraping

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, scraping, peticiones

Buen dia, Es un poco difícil de entender lo que busco lograr pero espero comprendan. Estoy buscando la forma de usar el elemento que contenga la celda en este caso palabras que usare para hacer peticiones y luego web-scraping en otra funcion.

La forma en que pensé fue en que después de 10 segundos `sleep(10)` pasara a la siguiente celda. Pero no me deja usar el contenido de esa celda, No usa el contenido para hacer la petición. Por lo tanto solo me extrae la estructura html sin que se haya hecho la petición.

Así que pensé en el método de cambiar de celda después de un numero determinado de clicks en el botón(tkinter) que ejecuta la Función de cambio de celdas. No se si de esa forma me dejara usar la palabra de esa celda antes de ser cambiada a la siguiente, Pero espero que si xD. Si me ayudaran con este método seria buenísimo, Yo soy demasiado nuevo y me pase el día investigando pero no encontré ni un ejemplo o guía de como lograrlo. :(

**NO FUNCIONA**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

path = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Codigos\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
sheet_ranges = wb.active

num1= 0
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
num4 = 0

def pb():
    global num1
    global num2
    global num3
    global anum4
    for i in range(1, 3):
        num1, num2, num3, num4 = sheet_ranges[f'A{i}:D{i}'][0]
        print(num1.value, num2.value, num3.value, num4.value)
        sleep(1)
pb()
a=  [num1]
a1= [num2]
a2= [num3]
a3= [num4]

celdas = [a]
celdas1 = [a1]
celdas2 = [a2]
celdas3 = [a3]

for cell in celdas:
   ap = cell
for cell1 in celdas1:
   ap1 = cell1
for cell2 in celdas2:
    ap2 = cell2
for cell3 in celdas3:
    ap3 = cell3
url = "https://tioanime.com/directorio"

url1 = "https://monoschinos.com/search"

payload = {'q':ap1} #peticiones

payload1 = {'q':ap2} #peticiones

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
r1 = requests.get(url1,params=payload1)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')

ta = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
print(ta)
```

**SI FUNCIONA**

Este si funciona pera solo puedo yo determinar el numero de celda que se hara, Pero yo quiero utilizar por ejemplo el metodo que pense en Despues de 24 clicks en el boton, Cambiara de celda y utilizare ese nuevo contenido de esa celda para hacer una peticion y luego scraping.

Aqui si me hace la peticion y por lo tanto un buen scraping se la busqueda.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pyautogui
import time
from threading import Thread

path = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Codigos\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
sheet = wb.active


a = 0
a1 = 0
a2 = 0
a3 = 0
def pb():
    global a
    global a1
    global a2
    global a3
    #nombre de anime en link-TioAnime
    a = sheet['A1'].value
    #nombre del anime-TioAnime
    a1 = sheet['B1'].value
    #------------------------------------------
    #nombre del anime-MonosChinos
    a2 = sheet['C1'].value
    #nombre del anime-MonosChinos
    a3 = sheet['D1'].value
pb()
celdas = [a]
celdas1 = [a1]
celdas2 = [a2]
celdas3 = [a3]
for cell in celdas:
   ap = cell
for cell1 in celdas1:
   ap1 = cell1
for cell2 in celdas2:
    ap2 = cell2
for cell3 in celdas3:
    ap3 = cell3

url = "https://tioanime.com/directorio"

url1 = "https://monoschinos.com/search"

payload = {'q':ap1}

payload1 = {'q':ap2}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
r1 = requests.get(url1,params=payload1)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')

ta = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
print(ta)
```

Comment: Es dificil comprenderlo cuando ni si quiera se puede ver el contenido de esa hoja excel. Quizás podrías ponerla aquí y se entendería mejor la pregunta